# Битрикс не выполняет SQL запрос

Tags: битрикс

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    user_id, 
    user_name, 
    `date`, 
    status, 
    `from`, 
    `where`, 
    model_plane, 
    flight_hours, 
    price 
FROM profile_orders 
WHERE 
    DATE(`date`) >= '2014.08.21' AND 
    DATE(`date`) <= '2014.08.21' 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

$DB->Query()
не выдаёт никаких ошибок, всё как по маслу, Но ничего не находит.
Тот же самый запрос, запущенный вручную, работает, как положено.

Comment: Мне интересно, почему напрямую работаете с SQL-запросами в Битриксе, это не рекомендуют? Для этого есть средства API, с их помощью все прекрасно можно сделать. Я вначале раньше тоже порывался писать запросы на SQL в Битриксе, потом умные товарищи наставили на стезю истины).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Жизнь - боль :)
Решил, поменяв:

```
 DATE(`date`)
```

на:

```
 DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%Y.%m.%d')
```

Comment: "bitrix - тормоз". это как раз про такие запросы. приведите ваше значение даты к формату хранения, а не наоборот. иными словами: "что проще: вам сконвертить две даты в скрипте или базе для каждой строки применить функцию конвертации даты по два раза а потом сравнить с вашими значениями?"

Comment: bitrix в свойствах дату хранит в виде строки, так что там просто никак иначе